# .NET 5 GRPC client call throws exception: Requesting HTTP version 2.0 with version policy RequestVersionOrHigher while HTTP/2 is not enabled

Tags: c#, grpc, .net-5

This is my first gRPC application. I'm attempting to invoke a server-streaming RPC call from a .NET 5 gRPC client (Grpc.Net.Client 2.35.0) which results in the following exception in my local development environment:

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error
> starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: Requesting HTTP version 2.0
> with version policy RequestVersionOrHigher while HTTP/2 is not
> enabled."

This occurs whether or not the server application is running. Here is the code I'm using to make the call:

```
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(@"http://localhost:5000");
var client = new AlgorithmRunner.AlgorithmRunnerClient(channel);
using var call = client.RunAlgorithm(new RunAlgorithmRequest());

while (await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
{

}
```

My understanding is that .NET 5 gRPC is supposed to have HTTP/2 enabled by default: why does the exception indicate that HTTP/2 is not enabled and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem sitting behind a corporate proxy and receiving this error message

```
An exception of type 'Grpc.Core.RpcException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: Connection refused SocketException: Connection refused", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused
```

I fully agree that your suggested workaround with bypassing all proxy settings by overwriting the *DefaultProxy* is legit and functional.

A slightly better approach would be not to hard code a 'bypass all proxy statement' in your code and use instead the *no_proxy* environment variable.
The purpose of this environment variable is to define a rule for excluding traffic destined to certain hosts

**Solution**

Activate the env. variable *no_proxy* for your development setup like

For linux

```
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

For Dockerfile

```
ENV no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

For a deep dive session about  [proxy environment variables](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/01/27/we-need-to-talk-no-proxy/)

It is important when you start your gRPC client application, that you check what the value of the read in environment variables is, because gRPC uses the *HttpClient* class under the hood, which considers all proxy environment variables. If the *no_proxy* value is not set, it has not effect.

```
var noProxy = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("no_proxy");
```

Answer (score 15):

After further investigation, this appears related to proxy settings on my machine related to my company's network setup. Specifically, I have the following environment variables defined:

> http_proxy https_proxy

.NET populates the HttpClient DefaultProxy from these environment variables. My company proxy appears to be interfering with HTTP/2 (unsupported?), preventing gRPC from working correctly. The workaround for local development is to manually set the default proxy for the HttpClient before making the gRPC call:

```
HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy();
                
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(@"http://localhost:5000");
var client = new AlgorithmRunner.AlgorithmRunnerClient(channel);
using var call = client.RunAlgorithm(new RunAlgorithmRequest());
```

This may represent a general problem with using gRPC through certain types of proxies.

Comment: Thanks, Jacob. This fixed my headache.

Comment: The same error seems to happens on client running on Windows7 with no proxy and using https. Seems like Windows7 doesn't support HttpClient using HTTP/2 with TLS.

Comment: @Dunge Confirming having another Win7 client spitting out this error

Comment: @Ray I ended up using grpc-web for Win7 customers. It's just a matter of adding 1-2 lines both in server and client to support it, then you leave an option in the interface to use it or not.

Comment: @Dunge Thanks for the idea. I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/59770858/777985 and replaced Grpc.Net.Client with Grpc.Core, which also only needed a few code adjustments.

Comment: I had this problem when starting `Grpc` client and service with fiddler running, your answer solves the issue. As soon as Fiddler is closed, the line is not needed. I didn't use `HTTPS` in this tests at all and `HTTP2` was correctly configured.

Answer (score 5):

If you found this page because your error occurs when Fiddler is running, I found the answer I required (to inspect WCF traffic) below. I only had to configure Fiddler, no code or env changes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73398308/5269981