# Fiddler with dotnet-isolated Az Function - Error starting gRPC call

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, fiddler, azure-functions-core-tools

I have a C# dotnet 5 Azure Function in VS2019 configured with "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated".

If I run the function in the dev environment (ctrl + F5) while Fiddler is running then I get the following error:

*Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: Requesting HTTP version 2.0 with version policy RequestVersionOrHigher while HTTP/2 is not enabled.*

The function will run fine if Fiddler is not running.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: As suggested in the below reference SO thread 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66500195/net-5-grpc-client-call-throws-exception-requesting-http-version-2-0-with-versi
The workaround for local development is to manually set the default proxy for the HttpClient before making the gRPC call

Answer (score 13):

I've made Fiddler work with an Azure Function project with two additions to the standard setup:

1. Add 127.0.0.1 to the bypass list
2. Add tls1.1 and tls1.2 to the supported protocols and skip decryption for 127.0.0.1

[image: Bypass list]

[image: HTTPS Decryption options]